# find triangular numbers between any given two numbers

Tags: python, python-2.7

My code is showing bellow

```
import math,sys

#create a list with numbers
def create_list():
    num_list=[]
    for num in range(int(input("insert start point: ")),int(input("Insert end point: "))):
        num_list.append(num)
    return num_list

#function to find triangular numbers
def get_triangles(numlist):
    triangles = []
    for i in numlist:
        if (check_triangle(i)):
            triangles.append(i)
    return triangles

#function to check number is triangular or not
def check_triangle(n):
    return math.sqrt((8*n)+1).is_integer()

#function main to run the process
def main():
    numlist = create_list()
    print(get_triangles(numlist))
```

Even though it seems like the task is completed it was not. I tried it with the range of  0 - 100000000(1*10^8) numbers . it is cause to stuck my laptop any method that can complete this task ?

Comment: Your program works, it is just inefficient when you are trying to find such big numbers. What is your question? Why do you need to check such a big range? Instead of checking each number individually, can you just generate the sequence of triangular number until you find one bigger than 10^8?

Comment: You're building a list of 100 million numbers, then copying it to a second list for no reason (and in the slowest way possible), *then* doing something else 100 million times. That's... going to take some time.

Comment: I make no claims about the quality of your algorithm - there are definitely better ways than checking each integer in your range - but a better way to implement your chosen algorithm is `triangles = itertools.ifilter(check_triangle, xrange(start, end))`. That returns an iterator that will yield triangular numbers; you can call `list(triangles)` if you actually need the list.

Comment: If you know where the formula in `check_triangle` came from, you should be able to solve for `n` for a given triangular number, right?  So you know exactly where to start looking.  Recall that `Tri(n) = n*(n+1)/2` .

Answer (score 2):

DO NOT PRINT A LIST THAT LARGE. Instead write it to a file, that way you can open the file afterward. The program can't efficiently write that much information into the console. I find that printing stuff to the console makes a programs a ton less efficient.

Additionally, I read some of the comments on your code and they state it isn't efficient and I would have to concur.

Here is piece of code I wrote up. It takes a bit of interpretation, but I was in a hurry. Just reply if you need help understanding it.

```
def getTriangles(input1,input2): #input1 is the min value and input2 is the max value
    li = [] #the list where all of the numbers will go
    i = 0 #an integer that acts how much another layer of the triangle would have
    j = 0 #the most current number that it is on
    while True: #I whipped up this algorithm in a couple minutes, so there is probably a more efficient way than just looping through all of them, but it is faster than the current one being used
        i += 1 #i has to increment to act as the increase of a side
        if j > input2: #if the value that could be added is greater than the max number, than just end the function and return the list
            return li
        if j >= input1: #if the number qualifies the minimum number requirements, then the program will add it to the list, otherwise it will ignore it and continue on with the function
            li.append(j)
        j += i #this simulates adding in another layer of the triangle to the bottom
```

This would be a way to use it:
    print(getTriangles(1,45))
I trust you can look up how to write content to a file.

Comment: thank you very much i got the code. i tried it with threads i sow a algorithm just as follow what do you think about this . i am new comer to the python. so thank you very much for the help

Comment: 'NAME : Chop-down algorithm 
TASK : increase the efficiency of searching tasks  in vary large domains
ALGORITHM :
assume Domain size is equal to M where M > 10e6
Start
   chop down the domain in to n parts where n <= M/[(M*5)/100]
   create n number of  individual threads (avoid resource killing)
   assign single sub domain to each thread
   perform searching
End'

Comment: The most efficient way  to make this happen is by having a function that can tell as the function to find triangular numbers is approximately equal, and then continuously do that until a value is found for the first one. Since you now have "n" you could continue on with a modified version of my function in several threads.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are just trying to generate all triangle numbers within a range.  If this is so, computing them directly is substantially quicker than checking via square root.

Note that you can generate triangular numbers by simply adding consecutive numbers.

```
T_0 = 0
T_1 = T_0 + 1 = 1
T_2 = T_1 + 2 = 3
T_3 = T_2 + 3 = 6
...
```

If you want to keep it simple, you can create a function to keep generating these numbers from `n = 0`, keeping them when they enter the desired range, and continue until it exceeds the upper bound.

```
def generate_triangular_numbers(a, b):
    """Generates the triangular numbers in [a, b] (inclusive)"""
    n, t = 0, 0
    triangles = []

    while t < a:
        n += 1
        t += n

    while t <= b:
        triangles.append(t)
        n += 1
        t += n

    return triangles
```

Comment: hi thank you for the comment but the problem is with the maximum range that i can use. for example min = 0 and max = 10000000000000 then it is not working or generating fault results..